# OpenCL: sincos vs native_cos and native_sin

Tags: macos, opencl, gpgpu, trigonometry

I understand that the answer for this question depends on the specific OpenCL implementation and the hardware, but I need to choose between `sincos` and `native_cos` followed by `native_sin` for using in a Mac app.

Which is expected to be faster?

Comment: Native ones will always be faster. They map 1:1 to a HW instruction, typically for GPUs this is a cos/sin vertex instruction. The precision is implementation defined. Normal sincos, will have beter accuracy, at the cost of the speed (depending on the system)

Comment: Just a minor correction and my 2 cents worth: native_* functions don't have to map 1:1 to hardware instructions (see pg 250 of the OpenCL 1.2 standard).  Depending on the implementation, they probably map to fewer instructions than the non-native version and hence will be a bit faster.  This also depends on the range of input values.  For example Nvidia's sin, cos and sincos implementations have a fast path for inputs below some value and a slow path for inputs above that value.  Hence your speed gain when using native_sin may depend on your input values.

Comment: Do native functions use specialized pipelines(less numerous than adders/multipliers) or they use all pipelines but within a hardware library scheduling to get result?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a mini benchmark testing all versions of a transcendental function and alter the kernel-string accordingly(prepending `native_` to a `cos` for example.) with the benchmark results. This would need event based profiling and be appropriate for portability. Then, once for every N iterations, it could re-bench and have minor changes accordingly if there was any error from the last bench.

You can even benchmark for permutations of a series of functions (such as using native for first function but non native on second, native on third in first version, then alternate nativeness on other 5 versions, benchmark all) to fit the code better on pipeline architecture where order of functions matter.